# What Is The Replacement For ubuntu-defaults-builder?

Tags: live-usb, iso

To make simple adjustments to the iso (e.g. change background add a few packages) I used to be able to do:

```
ubuntu-defaults-template ubuntu-defaults-mydistro
<modify a few config files>
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
ubuntu-defaults-image --package ubuntu-defaults-mydistro_0.1_all.deb
```

Then I would end up with `binary.hybrid.iso` and `livecd.ubuntu.iso`.

I could easily script this to create a modified ISO whenever a new version came out.

This no longer works though because `ubuntu-defaults-image` uses `syslinux-themes-ubuntu` which hasn't been published since Xenial and so you get the error `Unable to locate package syslinux-themes-ubuntu-focal`

The [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) page has over 100 commands and ends up using `uck` which no longer exists.

Is there a replacement for `ubuntu-defaults-builder` that I can script that only requires a few commands?

Comment: I gave CUBIC a try the other day and it was working for 20.04, not sure about 20.10. See: https://launchpad.net/cubic

Comment: I can't find any documentation for it and the launchpad page says "Cubic is a GUI wizard" without much info about how to use it or script it.

Comment: Try this to start,  https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/how-to-customize-ubuntu-or-linux-mint.html. there used to be a user manual on the net but I can't find it now.

Comment: I found in the answers on launchpad that you can't script Cubic: https://answers.launchpad.net/cubic/+question/677976